# why the marker is not visible in mapbox?

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, mapbox

I'm messing my head around mapbox but the marker is not visible no matter what i do here is my code

```
map.on('dblclick', function (e) {
            var el = document.createElement('div');
            el.setAttribute("style","width: 25px,height: 25px,border-radius: 50%,border:1px solid gray,background-color:lightblue");
            var letcoordinates = [e.lngLat.lng, e.lngLat.lat];
            // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
            debugger
            new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
            .setLngLat(letcoordinates)
            .addTo(map);
   });
```

i don't what what i'm doing wrong

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `setAttribute()`, the properties should be separated by a **semicolon**:

```
el.setAttribute("style","width: 25px;height: 25px;border-radius: 50%;border:1px solid gray;background-color:lightblue");
```

Result: https://codepen.io/eddydg/pen/vWZGGB?editors=1010